# Metal offscreen drawing without a window

Tags: objective-c, macos, metal

I need offscreen drawing in Metal without a visible window or in a console app in macOS. But MTKView requires a window.

Comment: The sole purpose of MTKView is to help you draw to the screen, so it's definitely not suitable/necessary for your case. What are you looking to do with the output? Write it to a file?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My app renders offscreen 3D content (a slideshow from images) and then copy the generated content to a system memory for video encoding.

Comment: I don't understand what is issue here?

Comment: I need create MTKView without a window.

Comment: @Igor You really don't want/need MTKView. You just need to render everything into a texture. MTKView is all about putting stuff on the screen.

Comment: How to create a Metal device without window or MTKView?

Comment: Thanks for your advices. I'll try offscreen rendering without MTKView. Sorry for my stupid questions, I'm new in Metal API.